# Is it possible to output all taxonomy terms in page--products.html.twig template?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I am using Drupal 8.7.5. I setup three different taxonomy types. They are Category, Types, and Tags. I have a custom post type called Products.  I created a View called Products and added that as a page in my main menu.  Then i used Devel to fill products with some dummy data.  All of that went very smooth.

Now, I want to output all of the categories, types and tags in my page--products.html.twig file in a select menu or checkboxes to create a filter system.

I've been looking around and I don't see how to get to these values from a page template.  Can anyone offer some clues?

Comment: You probably mean a faceted search, see https://www.drupal.org/project/facets

Comment: You could simply create Views blocks, one for each category, and place them on that page.

Comment: I'll mess with that but I guess I was confused how to control the output so that I can show them as a select menu or check boxes.

Comment: But this doesn't make a filter system, just demo elements without function. You should think about a Search API View and facets.

Comment: I want to use isotope.js to create a filter system.  I just need to know how to output the categories, tags, and types from the database to construct the drop down menus.  In wordpress, this is super easy to do.  It is not so clear how to do this in Drupal and then be able to modify the structure of the html.  I'll give the view a try and see what i can do.

Comment: Facets looks like it might be worth it to try it out. Thanks 4x4.

Comment: So i got the view to output the categories, types, and tags using an exposed filter.  Now i want to hook that up to isotope.  I actually got it working when i hard coded the select menus into the page, but i see that drupal outputs a bunch of json and that is what is rendered in the select menus.  It doesnt seem that isotope can hook into that because the html isnt there a the right time (maybe?) any suggestions?

Comment: We didnt use Facets. We ended up using exposed filters in the view.  Then, we loaded isotope, jqueryui and other javascript things in a library.  We had to wrap our js in a document.ready function in order for it to work.